# Shopify refund amount wrong when refund in pending state (Admin REST API)

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

My issue is in getting the expected refund total when the refund is in a "pending" state. Pending seems to mean the period between the refund being logged and the card transaction actually happening:

[image]

While it is pending, the refund (downloaded from the Admin REST API) does not have the expected total (as far as I have seen, it has net total of zero but I am not sure if this is always the case). The discrepancy seems to be due to an adjustment amount being present that offsets the actual order item refund. Later (I guess when the refund is no longer "pending"), the adjustment amount is reversed, so the refund net total is what is expected. Here is an image of the JSON downloaded from the REST API, showing this adjustment and its reversal:

[image]

My question is - how do I compute the expected net total of the refund at any time, i.e. ignoring these "special" adjustments? I cannot just ignore all adjustment amounts, because sometimes they represent a true refund, e.g. shipping. Do these "special" adjustments have some unique  property (I don't think I can assume kind="refund_discrepancy" is exclusive to them)?

If however there is no way to uniquely identify these "special" adjustments, is there a way to identify refunds that are in the "pending" state, and then I can ignore them until they are no longer pending (and therefore the totals are correct)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured out what is going on, but I cannot find any official documentation of this phenomena, only a few other reports from site owners such as [this one](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/multiple-order-adjustments-of-type-refund-discrepancy/td-p/881261).

When a refund is logged, there is an associated physical funds transfer to the customer. In the REST API data, the funds transfer is called the "transaction". Shopify may delay the execution of this transaction, and in this case the transaction has a status of "pending" and when complete changes to "success".

If the transaction starts with a pending status, Shopify adds a "discrepancy" adjustment to make the net value of the refund zero (I think the reason is to indicate that no physical refund has happened yet, maybe for reporting purposes). Later when the transaction is complete, another adjustment is added to reverse the first, i.e. making the net value of the refund correct.

So, to get the correct net value of the refund, find any transactions inside the refund with status="pending", then filter out adjustments (with kind="refund_discrepancy") that have the same value.